# How to display check mark character in jQuery datatables PDF export

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, datatable, character-encoding

I have the following table which uses the [datatables plugin](https://datatables.net/) for pagination, sorting and exporting.

Everything works great except the `check mark` in my `html` is not exported with the `pdf`, yet it is with `excel`. I want to get this working because I am going to remove the `checkbox` element in favour of clicking the table cell and toggling whether the `check mark` is present. **I really want to avoid using `'Y'/'N'` as indicators in any part of the table/exports.**

Has anyone come across this issue before or can offer any light, my instinct tells me it's something to do with the character encoding in PDF export library, but I don't want to go just go in and start editing library files because this issue (may)will be repeated if I ever need to upgrade the lib. In addition, I'm not totally sure what to look for.

**HTML**
[image: html view]

**Excel**
[image: excel view]

**PDF**
[image: pdf view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PROBLEM:

jQuery's Datatables uses pdfmake library for its eporting in PDF.

pdfmake uses only one font 'Roboto' as it's text font and as it so happens its char-set doesn't support the '✓' symbol.

You can have a look at all the characters 'Roboto' , pdfmake and subsequently Datatables supports here: https://www.fontspace.com/font-charmap/21071

This information was found at: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/1478

## **SOLUTION:**

You can change the font that Datatables uses when exporting to pdf using pdfmake to something that support the character symbol '✓'

1. create a new vfs_fonts.js file containing your font files

   - Create the examples/fonts subdirectory in your pdfMake code directory, if it doesn’t already exist.
   - Copy your fonts (and other files you wish to embed) into the examples/fonts subdirectory.
   - Run npm install (from the pdfMake directory) to ensure all prerequisites modules are installed.
   - Run gulp buildFonts to create a new build/vfs_fonts.js (you can update gulpfile.js to change the base directory path or to add an alternative config for the buildFonts task).
   - Include your new build/vfs_fonts.js file in your code (in the same way you include pdfmake.js or pdfmake.min.js).
   - The above buildFonts action embeds all files from examples/fonts (into a local key/value variable pdfMake.vfs) - not only fonts. Which means you could put images in there, run gulp buildFonts, and reference them by filename in your doc-definition object.
2. include this newly created font file in your document

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./pdfmake-0.1.37/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
   ```
3. add your fonts to pdfmake

   ```
   pdfMake.fonts = { 
       Arial: {
               normal: 'arial.ttf',
               bold: 'arialbd.ttf',
               italics: 'ariali.ttf',
               bolditalics: 'arialbi.ttf'
       }
   };
   ```
4. Add your font to the Datatable

   ```
   buttons = [
       {
           customize: function (doc) {
               doc.defaultStyle = 
               {
                   font: 'Arial'
               }
           }
       } 
   ]
   ```

Some helpful links:

[DataTables & PDFmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561932/datatables-pdfmake) - question on how to set a new font to the datatable

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/51827/how-i-change-font-family-in-pdf-export - datatable community question on how to change the font family.

Answer (score 2):

While writing a PDF, use unicode string for check mark exactly as below:

&#10003 followed by ;

like

<table border="2"><tr><td><Check mark: </td><td>&#10003;</td></tr></table>